# Reapplying jquery ui datepicker to class after adding fields via ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a form that contains the main data and the user can specify the category of this model by a dropdown field. When the user selects a type the type specific fields are loaded via ajax. This works pretty well but some of them have  `class="date"` which should add the datepicker. Of cause I know that wont work as long as I call the`datepicker` method again. So I do that again like this:

```
$(".date").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'
});
```

But it doesnt work. This is the same code I use to apply the datepicker the first time but on the secound time nothing happens. Does anyone see a failure here?

// Specifying the fail: Its not like the datepickers are removed from the working fields but hey are simpley not applied to the fields that were loaded via ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datepicker has to be **destroyed** first in order to add a new one.

So try this:

```
$(".date").datepicker("destroy").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but it doesnt work for me. I specified the problem because it seemed to be too unspecific.

Comment: @davidb you have to manually apply the datepicker to anything that was loaded via ajax. you cannot bind a datepicker live...

Comment: Why cant I apply `$(".date").datepicker`... after I loaded addiitional fields via ajax? Its not like they werent there and I also do this with my token inputs and it works eaven I identify them using a class.